# Encrypted/Decrypted data php

Tags: php, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt data from a form.I took the class that helps me to do that from:

https://github.com/o/crypt-php

The encrypt works but when I try to decrypt it gives me an error saying that:

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The given data does not appear to be encrypted with Crypt'

My code:

```
  //for encrypt(this works)
  require_once("Crypt.php");

  $crypt = new Crypt;
  $crypt->setKey('keykeykeyy');
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $crypt->setData($password);
  $encrypted = $crypt->encrypt();


  //for decrypt almost the same thing
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $crypt->setData($password);
  $decrypted = $crypt->decrypt();
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Would `$_POST['password']` really have the encrypted data in it?  First step to debugging should be to print out the values.

Comment: If this is an actual user password, you should not be using encryption, you should be using hashing.  Passwords should not be able to be decrypted.  PHP has built in functionality for handling this: [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: ...also, if you're actually trying to encrypt some data with the password _as_ a key, you should run it through [PBKDF2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) (or some other key-stretching KDF, such as scrypt) first. To make brute force password guessing attacks harder, you should also pass PBKDF2 a large iteration count (at least 10,000, preferably something closer to 1,000,000,000; beware of DoS attacks, though, if you let users easily execute a lot of very slow PBKDF2 calls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this lines

```
  //for decrypt almost the same thing
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $crypt->setData($password);
  $decrypted = $crypt->decrypt();
```

you are setting data for decrypt the raw password
instead that you need pass as data the password encrypted

```
  $crypt->setData($encrypted);
  $decrypted = $crypt->decrypt();
```

regards